# Unwanted behavior of PHP usort

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I have a problem with PHP `usort()`. Let's suppose I have an array like this (that's a simplification, I've not to work with names, and I have an array of objects, not arrays):

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Albert',      'last' => 'Einstein'),
    array('name' => 'Lieserl',     'last' => 'Einstein'),
    array('name' => 'Alan',        'last' => 'Turing'  ),
    array('name' => 'Mileva',      'last' => 'Einstein'),
    array('name' => 'Hans Albert', 'last' => 'Einstein')
);
```

As you can see, the array is sorted arbitrarily.

Now, if want to sort it by `last`, I do:

```
function sort_some_people($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['last'], $b['last']); }
usort($data, 'sort_some_people');
```

And I have:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [name] => Mileva       [last] => Einstein )
    [3] => Array ( [name] => Albert       [last] => Einstein )
    [1] => Array ( [name] => Lieserl      [last] => Einstein )
    [2] => Array ( [name] => Hans Albert  [last] => Einstein )
    [4] => Array ( [name] => Alan         [last] => Turing   )
)
```

That is ok, now they are sorted by `last`. But, as you can see, I've just completely lost the previous sorting. What am I saying? I want to preserve array sorting as it was before, but as a *secondary* sorting. I hope I was clear. **Practically** I want to sort data using something as `usort()` (so, a completely custom sorting), but if sorting field is identical between two items, I want to keep their *relative position* as it was before. Considering the given example, I want `Lieserl Einstein` to appear before `Mileva Einstein` because it was like this at beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting algorithms used in PHP have this property where the order is undefined if the items match.

If you need to keep the order, then you have to roll your own code.

Fortunately some one already has:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#38827

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Albert',      'last' => 'Einstein'),
    array('name' => 'Lieserl',     'last' => 'Einstein'),
    array('name' => 'Alan',        'last' => 'Turing'  ),
    array('name' => 'Mileva',      'last' => 'Einstein'),
    array('name' => 'Hans Albert', 'last' => 'Einstein')
);

function sort_some_people($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['last'], $b['last']);
}

function mergesort(&$array, $cmp_function = 'strcmp') {
    // Arrays of size < 2 require no action.
    if (count($array) < 2) return;
    // Split the array in half
    $halfway = count($array) / 2;
    $array1 = array_slice($array, 0, $halfway);
    $array2 = array_slice($array, $halfway);
    // Recurse to sort the two halves
    mergesort($array1, $cmp_function);
    mergesort($array2, $cmp_function);
    // If all of $array1 is <= all of $array2, just append them.
    if (call_user_func($cmp_function, end($array1), $array2[0]) < 1) {
        $array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
        return;
    }
    // Merge the two sorted arrays into a single sorted array
    $array = array();
    $ptr1 = $ptr2 = 0;
    while ($ptr1 < count($array1) && $ptr2 < count($array2)) {
        if (call_user_func($cmp_function, $array1[$ptr1], $array2[$ptr2]) < 1) {
            $array[] = $array1[$ptr1++];
        }
        else {
            $array[] = $array2[$ptr2++];
        }
    }
    // Merge the remainder
    while ($ptr1 < count($array1)) $array[] = $array1[$ptr1++];
    while ($ptr2 < count($array2)) $array[] = $array2[$ptr2++];
    return;
}

mergesort($data, 'sort_some_people');

print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Albert
            [last] => Einstein
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lieserl
            [last] => Einstein
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mileva
            [last] => Einstein
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Hans Albert
            [last] => Einstein
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alan
            [last] => Turing
        )

)
```

Voila!

Comment: Accepted. Anyway I solved in a more concise way. Before `usort()` I stored original array position (index) in every object (i.e. `$data[$i]->original_index = $i`), and then I checked for this value in my comparison function when the first comparison returns `0` (i.e. identical sorting value). Quite plain and clever, isn't it? :) Thank you all!

Comment: Brilliant idea @lorenzo-s.  I did the same and it worked perfectly, with a lot less custom code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$compare = strcmp($a['last'], $b['last']);
if ($compare == 0)
    $compare = strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
return $compare
```

Comment: See comment I left on Tim Cooper answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of the result that you want, rather than the result you're getting

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a [stable sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aStable_sorts), which php doesn't offer. Beware that even if it may appear stable sometimes, there's no guarantee of it, and so likely to misbehave given certain inputs.

If you know the sorting criteria of the other columns, you can resort it all at once to get the desired behavior. [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/array_multisort) does this. The following is a bit more powerful way in that the comparison logic is completely user defined.

```
// should behave similar to sql "order by last, first"
$comparatorSequence = array(
    function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['last'], $b['last']);
    }
  , function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['first'], $b['first']);
    }
  // more functions as needed
);

usort($theArray, function($a, $b) use ($comparatorSequence) {
    foreach ($comparatorSequence as $cmpFn) {
        $diff = call_user_func($cmpFn, $a, $b);
        if ($diff !== 0) {
            return $diff;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

If you really need a stable sort because the existing order of elements isnt well defined, try writing your own sort. [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) for example is very easy to write. This is a good solution so long as the number of elements in your lists are relatively small, otherwise look to implement one of the other stable sorting algorithms.

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not know the original sort criteria (there is none). I did not know that there is a precise definition for sorting algorithms that behave as I stated. I see bubble sort and merge sort (the ones which I know best) are stable sorts... So... *[OT]* What algorithm PHP use internally?!?

Comment: php uses a version of quicksort

Comment: I see. He rewrite merge sort in PHP, that (now I can say) it's stable. Best answer for now, but I will wait a little to see if someone will have a more concise idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sort_some_people($a, $b)
{
    $compareValue = 10 * strcmp($a['last'], $b['last']);
    $compareValue += 1 * strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    return $compareValue;
}
```

Sample: http://codepad.org/zkHviVBM

This functions uses each digit of the decimal system for a sort criteria. The one that comes first has the highest digit. Might not be the smartest, but works for me.

Comment: Same as Mark Baker and Tim Cooper. I'm sorry, I asked question in the worng way. I updated it now.